# Displaying object ToString() value in View

Tags: razor, view, asp.net-core-mvc, tag-helpers

I have an ASP .Net Core MVC 1.1 web app. In it, I have a view - **Details.cshtml** which simply displays a selected record:

```
@model InspectionsData.Models.House

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Details";
}

<h2>Details</h2>

<div>
    <dl class="dl-horizontal"> 
        @*<dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Id)
        </dd>*@
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Street1)
        </dt>
        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Street1)
        </dd>
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Street2)
        </dt>
        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Street2)
        </dd>
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Street3)
        </dt>
        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Street3)
        </dd>
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.City)
        </dt>
        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.City)
        </dd>
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Region)
        </dt>
        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Region)
        </dd>
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Country)
        </dt>
        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Country)
        </dd>
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PropertyType)
        </dt>
        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.PropertyType)
        </dd>
    </dl>
</div>
<div>
    <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@Model.Id">Edit</a> |
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>
```

In the above, "PropertyType" is a class that looks like this:

```
public partial class PropertyType
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string PropertyTypeName { get; set; }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return PropertyTypeName;
        }
    }
```

As you can see, I am overriding the ToString() method in the hope that the View would execute ToString() when it rendered, and therefore display the value of PropertyType, but it's not doing that. So it's just coming up blank. I tried to do this in my view:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.PropertyType.ToString())
```

But it didn't like that one bit (Error: **InvalidOperationException: Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions**)
Will I have to add a string field to my PropertyType class and bind the View to that for the property type to be displayed? Or is there perhaps a more elegant solution I'm not aware of?

Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be the quite simple:

```
@Model.PropertyType.ToString()
```

Comment: One thing though juunas, as far as I understand, your solution (@Model.PropertyType.ToString()) won't use display templates. In this case, that's fine. But I'm wondering what other solution there might be if I had decorated this property in my model and wanted it displayed as such.

Comment: Yeah, that is true ;) The problem is that as the error you got says, it can't map your expression to a property. What you thought of where you make a string property and then use that, would work.